# VBA loop to paste each row of data to a Template, and save-as?

Tags: excel, loops

The source report and output template are super clean (and have identical columns), so this really shouldn't be as difficult as I'm making it.

I have ~100 rows of pivot table sales data and would like to copy/paste each row (aside from the header) to a standard template file, and save by Company Name.

The source data file (ApportionmentData.xlsm) contains data in rows A: AJ.  The tab name is [Data].

Column "A" contains the Company Name (each is unique).
Column "B:AI" contains the sales data (each column header is unique)
Column "AJ" contains the File Name I have concatenated and would like to use for the save-as.

The destination file (Template.xlsm) contains a tab called [TBSource], where I would like to paste a single row (TO ROW 2), before saving-as and looping.  I've made the headers of both tabs consistent to try to make this less complex, so I only need to Copy/Paste row 2 on the first iteration.

After pasting to Row 2 of [TBSource] I would like to save-as by the value in column "AJ2", and move on to copy/pasting ROW 3 of [Data] to the next TEMPLATE (Row 2).

The goal is to have a separate file for each row of the [Data] tab.

Sub CreateOrganizers()

```
Dim wbstart As Workbook, wbtarget As Workbook 'You need As for each one, otherwise they are variants
Dim strPath As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wbstart = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbtarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Macro\Template Organizer\Template.xlsm")
With wbstart.Sheets("Data")
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 36)).Copy Destination:=wbtarget.Sheets("TBSource").Range(wbtarget.Sheets("TBSource").Cells(i, 1), wbtarget.Sheets("TBSource").Cells(i, 36))
        wbtarget.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & "\" & .Cells(i, 36).Value
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Finished"
```

End Sub

My current version runs the loop but for each iteration it continues to grow (instead of pasting a single row).  I think I'm pretty close here but could use a second opinion!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!  ELATED!  This section should reflect the row you want to paste the data, "2" instead of "i".

Destination:=wbtarget.Sheets("TBSource").Range(wbtarget.Sheets("TBSource").Cells(2, 1), wbtarget.Sheets("TBSource").Cells(2, 36))